# Check if a dictionary is present in a list of dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

How can check, whether a list of dictionaries contains a specific dictionary?

```
private List<Dictionary<string, object>> detailsDictionary;
private Dictionary<string, object> selecteItem;
```

Is there a direct way to check if `selectedItem` is in `detailsDictionary`?

Answer:

```
bool isPresent=false;
foreach(Dictionary<string,object> dic in detailsDictionary)
                    {
                        if (DictionaryExtensionMethods.ContentEquals(selectedItem, dic))
                        {
                            isPresent= true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }


public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool ContentEquals<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> otherDictionary)
    {
        return (otherDictionary ?? new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>())
            .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
            .SequenceEqual((dictionary ?? new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>())
                               .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key));
    }
}
```

I manually compare each dictionary in list with selected dictionary and make isPresent=true if the two dictionary are equal. I think its a long process and there should be some other easy way.

Comment: You can use `Contains` assuming your doing a reference search and not a search for a dictionary with the same keys and values.

Comment: What should happen if the Dictionaries contains the same key but have different values?

Comment: If you are thinking about comparing dictionaries for equality then you are pursuing the wrong solution.  Don't ask an XY question please.

Comment: I am not thinking of comparing i want to know just weather a list of dictionary object contains  a dictionary in it or not? And while checking key and value of the dictionary should exactly match.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether or not any item is in a list by using the [`IList.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
bool contains = detailsDictionary.Contains(selectedItem);
```

Note that this has *O(N)* complexity, as it has to go though every item in the list, until it finds a match or runs through the whole list. If this is a problem, you may want to cache your lists using a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) method that *(in most cases)* works much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response friend. But above code not working even though detailsDictionary contains selectedItem value the expression "detailsDictionary.Contains(selectedItem);" returns false

Comment: @Joee Does it contain *the same list* or *a list containing the same items*? Those are two different things.

Comment: I dont know the exact answer for your question but my need is  i have List of dictionary(ex:List<Dictionary<string, object>> detailsDictionary) and it contains one dictionary that has same key ,value and count as  (ex:Dictionary<string, object> selecteItem) this dictionary. I want to find weather "selectedItem" dictionary is in "detailsDictionary"

Answer (score 0):

Or if you mean where `selectedItem` and the elements of `detailsDictionary` share the same keys, rather than that they are identical objects:

```
detailsDictionary.Any(dict => dict.Count == selectedItem.Count && dict.Keys.All(key => selectedItem.ContainsKey(key)));
```

Obviously this is slower and like Gediminas mentions, there is likely a better way if speed is of the essence.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I checked the above code it doesn't return bool value instead it returns number 282

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used in my code checks whether the `selectedItem`'s values are present in each `detailsDictionary` item,

```
detailsDictionary.Any(x=> x.Values.SequenceEqual(selectedItem.Values));
```

This assums the list of dicts are all dicts of the same kind (same headers).
If not, you could do the following:

```
detailsDictionary.Any(x=> x.Values.SequenceEqual(selectedItem.Values) &&
                          x.Keys.SequenceEqual(selectedItem.Values));
```

However I dont know much about the efficiency of this method.